# How do I get current page ID in Wordpress customizer file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to hide or show customizer settings based on what page I am viewing similar to `active_callback' => 'is_front_page'`, however, I haven't found a way how to access the current page ID from my `customizer.php` file. I want to be able to use `active_callback' => 'is_specific_page'` through a custom callback based on current page ID like so:

```
    function is_specific_page() {

        // LOGIC RETURNS TRUE OR FALSE DEPENDING ON CURRENT PAGE

    }
```

I've tried using all of the following to no avail:

`global $post; $post->ID();` 
`global $wp_query; $post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;`
`get_the_ID();`

Thank you in advanced for your help!

Comment: Can you try, global $post; $post->ID; (without the brakets)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. `$post` variable seems to be empty.

Comment: Give it a try using get_queried_object_id() instead.

Comment: Didn't work. Hmm... I'm new to PHP so if there was a way I could log Wordpress' PHP objects to see what's happening inside, similar to `console.log(obj)` that would help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh I figured out how to do that with `json_encode()` :)

Comment: For future reference you can use print_r( $object ) to print the object.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Alex welcome to stackoverflow.

Here is how you could compare the current page path to a specific path and find a match

```
function is_specific_pages(){
  $current_path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];//returns page path with leading slash

  //check if page path is one of the specific pages
  if( $current_path == '/page-1'){
   return true;
  }elseif( $current_path == '/page-2'){
   return true;
  }else{ 
   return false; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for this! The reason why I wanted to use IDs is in the case of changed URIs which would happen automatically if the page's title changes.

Comment: No problem. Its possible to change the page title without updating the path (slug). so you can keep the URI he same and adjust the title as needed, if nothing else works this can be a fallback.

Comment: If this problem lingers I'll have to use your solution. Thank you so much!